# How to use Asynchronous Callbacks in Jersey 2 in tomcat 7

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, asynchronous, jersey-2.0

How to use asynchronous callbacks of jersey 2 in tomcat server.
I found some examples in **Jersey manual : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8496**.

But the issue occurs when I'm tring to test following code with this: **https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8615** code as mentioned on Jersey 2 Manual.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**As, manual version has been changed, I'm posting the codes over here:**

**This is my Service:**

```
            import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
            import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
            import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
            import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse; 
            import javax.ws.rs.container.CompletionCallback; 
            import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended; 
            import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 
            import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; 

            @Path("/resource") 
            public class AsyncResource { 
                private static int numberOfSuccessResponses = 0; 
                private static int numberOfFailures = 0; 
                private static Throwable lastException = null; 

                @GET 
                public void asyncGetWithTimeout(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) { 
                System.out.println("AsyncResource.asyncGetWithTimeout()"); 
                    asyncResponse.register(new CompletionCallback() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void onComplete(Throwable throwable) { 
                            if (throwable == null) { 
                                // no throwable - the processing ended successfully 
                                // (response already written to the client) 
                                numberOfSuccessResponses++; 
                            } else { 
                                numberOfFailures++; 
                                lastException = throwable; 
                            } 
                        } 
                    }); 

                    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void run() { 
                            String result = veryExpensiveOperation(); 
                            asyncResponse.resume(result); 
                        } 

                        private String veryExpensiveOperation() { 
                            // ... very expensive operation 
                        return "Hi"; 
                        } 
                    }).start(); 
                } 
            }
```

**This is client:**

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig(); 
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig); 

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/Jersey2.5Service/rest"); 
    WebTarget target = webTarget.path("resource"); 

    final AsyncInvoker asyncInvoker = target 
                    .request().async(); 
    final Future<Response> responseFuture = asyncInvoker.get(); 
    System.out.println("Request is being processed asynchronously."); 
    final Response response = responseFuture.get(); 
            // get() waits for the response to be ready 
    System.out.println("Response received." +response.readEntity(String.class));
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>  
      <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>  
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer  
       </servlet-class>  
       <init-param>  
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
         <param-value>main.java</param-value>  
       </init-param>  
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
     </servlet>  
     <servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
     </servlet-mapping>
```

**These are the jars I'm using:**

```
    asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    cglib-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    guava-14.0.1.jar 
    hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    hk2-locator-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    hk2-utils-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar 
    javax.inject-2.2.0-b21.jar 
    javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar 
    javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar 
    jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar 
    jersey-client.jar 
    jersey-common.jar 
    jersey-container-servlet-core.jar 
    jersey-container-servlet.jar 
    jersey-server.jar 
    org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar 
    osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar 
    persistence-api-1.0.jar 
    servlet-api-3.0.jar 
    validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

These errors are coming:

```
Jan 31, 2014 4:06:53 PM org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter suspend
WARNING: Attempt to put servlet request into asynchronous mode has failed. Please check your servlet configuration - all Servlet instances and Servlet filters involved in the request processing must explicitly declare support for asynchronous request processing.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1031)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl$ExtensionImpl.suspend(AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.suspend(ResponseWriter.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.suspend(ServerRuntime.java:758)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 31, 2014 4:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [HelloServlet] in context with path [/Jersey2.5Service] threw exception [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.] with root cause
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the source of your servlet? 
Do you import both Jersey modules, as per [Jersey User Guide section 4.7.3](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet.containers) ?

Comment: Are you using Servlet 3.0? Can you post web.xml if you have any? Do you have any filters declared? What's the exact version of Tomcat you're using? (There were couple of issues with certain Tomcat versions e.g. 7.0.16, 7.0.30 - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html)

Comment: Are you using `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in your **web.xml**'s `<servlet>...</servlet>` ?

Comment: @DanielDrozdzewski No i'm not using any such tags..

Comment: @DanielDrozdzewski ok I used that, still this error is comming:   java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/D:/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.47-vJ2/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to jar:file:/D:/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.47-vJ2/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/Jersey2.5Client/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class

Comment: Is your web.xml declaring servlet 3.0 ? 

e.g. 

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

    </web-app>

Comment: @anji the class cast comes most likely from the fact that you have the same jar included twice once in the `lib` folder of your Tomcat and once in the `WEB-INF/lib` or your war file - try having only one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST async operation throws ProcessingException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203157/rest-async-operation-throws-processingexception)

Answer (score 8):

For me the solution was to add support for Async in a Servlet Filter. The error message gave me a hint:

Attempt to put servlet request into asynchronous mode has failed. Please check your servlet configuration - all Servlet instances **and Servlet filters involved** in the request processing must explicitly declare support for asynchronous request processing

I am using Spring for Dependency Injection and using the default Jersey servlet. For Spring I use a Delegating Filter Proxy. I needed to declare for the Filter asycn support true.

So for the servlet:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myserlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>        
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

AND add async support true for the the Spring filter as well.

```
<filter>
        <description>Spring filter</description>
        <display-name>spring-filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>springFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
```

I hope this might help for you and others.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but for people who are facing this issue Please update Tomcat Server to the Latest Version 8.** . Tomcat starting from version 8 has support for Async Processing.

Answer (score 1):

For Async callback you can use Guava lib. For example:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ManagedAsync
public void getBooks(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response){

ListenableFuture<Collection<Book>> bookFuture = dao.getBooksAsync();
    Futures.addCallback(bookFuture, new FutureCallback<Collection<Book>>() {

        public void onSuccess(Collection<Book> books){
            response.resume(books);
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown){
            response.resume(thrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my book DAO I have:

```
BookDao(){
    books = new HashMap<String,Book>();

    Book b1 = new Book();

    service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));               
}

Collection<Book> getBooks(){

    return(books.values());
}

ListenableFuture<Collection<Book>> getBooksAsync(){

    ListenableFuture<Collection<Book>> future = 
            service.submit(new Callable<Collection<Book>>() {
                public Collection<Book> call() throws Exception{
                    return getBooks();
                }
            });
    return(future);
}
```

Comment: Starting with Java 8, CompletableFutures are built-in and act much like Guava's ListenableFuture's, they may be preferable going forward

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but upgrading to tomcat 9 will resolve this issue, without you modifying anything in the server